# Why isn't this perl prog printing about the translated text?

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl and programming in general, and I just found out about regular expressions and the substitution operator.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(LEET, "leet.txt") or die "Can't open leet.txt: $!\n";
while($line = <LEET>) {
    $line =~ s/4/a/gi, s/3/e/gi;
}
print $line;
```

Why doesn't his print anything? I want to make a leet speak translator that opens up a text file and prints out the translated text.

Answer (score 3):

You are only printing the *last* line. Try moving the `print` inside your loop:

```
while($line = <LEET>) {
    $line =~ s/4/a/gi;
    $line =~ s/3/e/gi;
    print $line;
}
```

I've also used two separate regex substitutions, you can't combine them in the way you've shown in your question.

Note that Perl also has the `tr` operator, which is another way of doing both (single-character) substitutions in one step:

```
$line =~ tr/43/ae/;
```

Comment: I put it inside, and it only prints the standard text that was written in the file, and has no substituted all as for 4s and es for 3s.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `s/a/4/gi`, it's unclear from your question which way you are translating. Also, you can't do two substitutions in quite the way you've shown. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ahh, I see! You are correct, I mean s/a/4/gi. Thank you, sir! You have just showed me how regexprs work in perl(and I assume that regexprs are fairly universal in syntax).

Comment: Technically, you've learned how *substitutions* work in Perl, with a very simple one-character regex. :)

Comment: Actually, the OP is printing the line *after* the last line, when `$line` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it (leet to english). You can add more keys as needed. To translate english to leet, just use a reversed hash: `%english = reverse %leet;`

A perhaps simpler solution is to use `tr///` for the substitution. E.g. `tr/43/ae/`.

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %leet = ( '4' => 'a', '3' => 'e' ); 
my $rx = join '|', keys %leet; 
while (<>) {
    s/($b)/$l{$1}/eg; 
    print;
}
```

**Usage:** `script.pl file.txt > output.txt`